# Retrieving statistic data in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, statistics, dao

I've got a table File for which I created a hibernate entity with fields:

> archiveDate: Date,
>   createDate: Date,
>   copyDdate: Date,
>   modifiedDate: Date,
>   fileSourceId: Long,
>   fileSize: Long

I have to create a DAO for retrieving statistic data like how many files were archived in a given period of time in given intervals (daily, weekly, monthly, annually) for specified fileSourceId. Like if dao receives arguments like this:

> fileSourceId = 1, startDay = '2012/01/01', endDate = '2012/02/01', interval = 'weekly'

it should return some objects like this:

> {fileSourceId = 1, endDate = (end date of the first week), fileCount = 100, sizeSum = 10000 }
>   {fileSourceId = 1, endDate = (end date of the second week), fileCount = 120, sizeSum = 30000 }

and so on. I would like to avoid doing calculations like counting and summing on the java side as there's a couple of hundred of thousands files.

Is it possible to create a query or criteria to do this in Hibernate or it's better to do some view in database (Oracle) and query this view. I would like to avoid any oracle specific function in query because we don't want to be bound to one database (especially that we use h2 as our testing database in integration testss). How would you resolve this problem?